# Change coordinates for origin in scatter plot with centred axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pycharm

I have some datasets that I'm visualizing in a scatter plot. I have a bunch of mean values, and a global mean. What I'm after, but cant really achieve,is to have a scatter plot that is centered in the plot, while also placing the origin at the global mean.

This is the code that defines the layout of the plot:

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.suptitle('Example')
plt.xlabel('x (pixels)')
plt.ylabel('y (pixels)')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.scatter(x_data, y_data, color=color, alpha=0.08, label=csv_file_name)
ax.plot(global_mean[0], global_mean[1], color='green',
            marker='x', label='Global mean')
```

This produces the following plot (the ax.scatter() is called multiple times for each dataset, but it's not in the code above):

[image: Example plot]

I've tried playing around with the `ax.set_position()` parameters but nothing have worked well so far. Is there a way to do what I'm after with matplotlib, or do I need to use some other plot library?

Comment: Well, something is responsible for this behavior that we cannot reproduce. Why would all axes disappear if you just disable some? Do they disappear if you move one axis or if you disable one axis? You may also want to add more information on your environment - matplotlib, Python, OS versions. Working here: matplotlib 3.3.3, Python 3.8 and matplotlib 2.0.0 Python 3.6 on Win 10

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ax.spines()` method to move them around.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#generate some random data
x = np.linspace(1,2, 100)
y = [random.random() for _ in range(100)]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

# original plot
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax.scatter(x, y)

# same plot, but with the spines moved
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
ax2.scatter(x, y)
# move the left spine (y axis) to the right
ax2.spines['left'].set_position(('axes', 0.5))
# move the bottom spine (x axis) up
ax2.spines['bottom'].set_position(('axes', 0.5))
# turn off the right and top spines
ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a solution I've tried, but doing so removes the spines completely for me.. Not sure if there is something else in my code that "overrides" it.

Comment: Are you working in a specific environment like Jupyter notebook, Google Colabs, Spyder, you name it that makes things "easier" for you backstage? If so, this should be tagged and mentioned in the question. It is not clear why this code should remove all axes.

Comment: @Mr. T I am using PyCharm, but am not aware of that it does something like that.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.T, you're right, have made the necessary edit.